# Qual a diferença entre match_parent e fill_parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

Quando estou editando o layout xml sempre fico confuso ao escolher entre o  `match_parent` e o `fill_parent`, e acabo por sempre achar que estou fazendo tudo de forma errada por não saber o que são cada um deles ou se são iguais.

Alguém poderia explicar qual a funcionalidade de cada um?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Qual a diferença entre match_parent e fill_parent ?**

Eles são a mesma coisa (no Nível API 8+).

Sim, MATCH_PARENT e FILL_PARENT são apenas diferentes nomes de constantes para o mesmo valor inteiro (`-1` se você está curioso) usado para especificar o modo de layout de um `View` dentro de seu `parent`.

O `fill_parent` foi renomeado para `match_parent` pois o problema com o antigo nome  era que implicava a afetar as dimensões do `parent`, enquanto `match_parent` melhor descrevia o comportamento resultante - correspondendo a dimensão com o `parent`.

**Qual a função do match_parent ?**

A função do `match_parent` é de dar um valor especial para o height ou o width solicitado por um View.

Use `match_parent` pois não há diferença caso você esteja em versões do API 8+,e já que celulares => Android 2.2 é aconselhável usar `match_parent`,mas por questão de compatibilidade para versões anteriores ainda existe `fill_parent`.

> OBS : Em versões do Android API do 1.6 á 2.1 é aconselhável usar `fill_parent` pois usando `match_parent` nestas versões ocorrem certos erros,então nestas versões de API use `fill_parent`.

Segundo a própria documentação oficial do Android,ele especifica que são a mesma coisa e que não há diferença em usar um ou outro.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Agradeço a explicação detalhada, acho que vou ter de fazer muitas mudanças então, agora, no caminho certo. =)

Answer (score 2):

O **fill_parent** não é mais usado, ele está obsoleto.

Foi substituido pelo match_parent, você até pode usar o **fill_parent**, mas pode acontecer alguns "defeitos" na aplicação.

Então é melhor usar o atual mesmo que é o **macth_parent**.

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente, nenhuma. Os dois são a mesma coisa.
Link da documentação [aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

`fill_parent` foi renomeado para `match_parent` na API 8 e maiores. Tente usar sempre `match_parent`

Answer (score 2):

Na prática, não há diferença.

`match_parent` substituiu `fill_parent` a partir da **API Level 8**.

[Veja a documentação do Android:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT)